# JavaScript testing in a PHP application without node or express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing

At work, I have been tasked with researching JavaScript testing frameworks. I am completely new to JavaScript testing. All of the frameworks I can find are strictly for Node or Express.

We're looking for a way to test JavaScript in a PHP/Apache environment with Javascript scattered all over the app - each module has it's own js file.

Yes, this is an app built in 2010, and we're turning it into a React/Node app down the road.

But for now, is this just a lost cause?

Comment: Is the javascript on the frontend or on the backend?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca front end. Everything backend is handled by PHP.

Comment: There are front-end testing frameworks that run on node, but it doesn't mean your application needs to be a node application, just that the runtime they run on is node. Anyway, you may want to take a look at [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/), specifically [this section](https://mochajs.org/#running-mocha-in-the-browser)